# Geo-aware partitioning in cassandra

Tags: geolocation, cassandra, bigdata

I'm am currently planning to setup a service that should be (sooner or later) globally available with high demands on availability and fault tolerance. There will be both a high read and hight write ratio and the system should be able to scale on demand.

A more special property of my planned service is, that the data will be extremely bound to a certain geo-location - e.g. in 99.99% of all cases, data meant for a city in the USA will **never** be queried from Europe (actually even data meant for a certain city will unlikely be queried from the city next to that city).

What I want to minimize is:

1. Administration overhead
2. Network latency
3. Unnecessary data replication (I don't want to have a full replication of the data meant for Europe in USA)

In terms of storage technologies I think that my best storage solution would be cassandra. The options that I see for my use-case are:

1. Use a completely isolated cassandra cluster per geo-location combined with a manually configured routing service that chooses the right cluster per insert/select query
2. Deploy a global cluster and define multiple data centers for certain geo-locations to ensure high availability in that regions
3. Deploy a global cluster without using data centers
4. Deploy a global cluster without using data centers and manipulate the partitioning to be geo-aware. My plan here is to manipulate the first 3 bits of the partition-key based on the geo-location (e.g. 000: North America, 001: South America, 010: Africa, 011: South/West Europe, etc.) and to assign the *remaining* bits by using a hash algorithm (similar to cassandras random partitioner).

The disadvantage of solution 1 would probably be a huge administrative overhead and a lot of manual work; the disadvantage of the second solution would be a huge amount of unnecessary data replication; and the disadvantage of the third solution would be a quite high network latency due to random partitioning across the world.

Therefore, in theory, I like solution 4 most. Here I would have a fair amount of administrative overhead, a low amount of unnecessary data replication and a decent availability. However, to implement this (as far as I know) I will need a ByteOrderPartitioning, which is highly disrecommended from many sources.

Is there a way to implement a solution close to solution 4 without using ByteOrderPartitioning, or is this a case where ByteOrderPartitioning *could* make sense or am I missing one obvious fifth solution?

Answer (score 2):

Reconsider option 2.

Not only will it solve your problems. It will even solve geo-redundancy for you. As you mentioned you need to have high availability. Having one copy in a different datacenter sounds good in case that one of the datacenters dies.

If you are dead set on refraining from replication between DCs, then thats an option too. You can have multiple DCs over different regions without replicating between them.

Comment: I agree that having **one or two** backup DCs in the case of an outage is a good idea, but I dislike the idea of shipping *all* data to *every* geo-location, because this will easily result in 10 times more storage requirements per geo-location and probably 100 times more traffic among locations.

Comment: What is the reason all data has to be shipped to every location? You can specify where it should go. You could restrict replication to only replicate to neighboring cities.

Comment: This restriction of replications to neighboring locations would be exactly what I need. But after reading several articles about data partitioning and replication, it seems only to be possible to specify a replication factor per DC, but AFAIK I cannot manipulate that a certain date is only stored in one (or possibly one backup) DC